# How can I get the size of each compressed frame of a video?

Tags: python-3.x, video, video-streaming, mp4, video-processing

Suppose I have a video file (let's say mp4).  How can I get the sizes of all frames in compressed format (i.e. get the I, P, B frame sizes)?

Ultimately, what I want to do is build a streaming simulator that will take as input a video and output the amount of data, indexed by time, that would be generated if the video was streaming in real time (I'm interested in the amount of instantaneous compressed data that would be generated over time, the content of the data doesn't matter).  So for example, if I have a 60fps video I would have an amount of data that is generated at each interval of 1/60s.

Is there an easy way to do this in Python3?

Comment: Since it's an MP4, you could check the entries in the **STSZ** atom. See [one reference](https://wiki.multimedia.cx/index.php/QuickTime_container#stsz). Open your file in a **hex editor** and search for text "stsz". Manually practice getting the info you need then write a Python app to do the same task with those same MP4 bytes. You'll need to **extract the FPS** then use it to calculate the frame number range for your chosen time, then sum up the sizes as listed (from the starting frame number up to last one for your expected time range)

Comment: PS: I assumed you were using a random example 60FPS. If you definitely know the FPS then simply sum up every 60 entries in STSZ to know how much bytes are involved in that 1 second interval